# SQL database import #1046 error

Tags: database, errors, sql, backup

As I am reuploading a WP website backup on a new host and importing the SQL database from phpMyAdmin, how do I solve this #1046 error ?

```
Error

SQL Request:
—
— Table structure for table tranx_commentmeta
—

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tranx_commentmeta

MySQL replied : Documentation
#1046 – No database selected
```

I can only read this file from a text reader.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you create and select a database to import to?

Comment: no, i just imported the file. You mean I should create a new database from scratch and then import my DB within the new one?

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot Howdy_McGee :-)

Comment: Error establishing a database connection :( 
I updated the wp-config.php to enter the newly created db name, db user & password but it didn't work. Any clues why? Thanks!!

Comment: I found the silly tiny error : in the wp-config.php file the DB unsername was using the wrong kind of brackets character... ' ' instead of ‘ ’
('DB_NAME', ‘db_name’); SHOULD BE ('DB_NAME', 'db_name');

Beware Kids!